# Search field and button

Tags: php, html, css

I have a search field and a button beside. It works totally fine and everything. But on mobile when you type in something and click on the phones keyboard "search" it goes to 404 error. But when i type in something and click on the "search button" it works. I just want to also to be able to click "search" on the phones keyboard without it going to 404.

This is my search field and button:

```
<div id="search" class="search" style="margin-left: 20px;">
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Hvad leder du efter?.." name="search" value="<?php if(isset($search)) echo $search; ?>" />
<button type="submit" class="button-search"></button>
```

I just dont understand why the "search button" works and not the "search" on phone keyboard

Comment: there's hardly any php here and how you're trying to send this.

Answer (score 0):

Insert an additional hidden submit into the form.

```
<input type="submit" style="display: none"/>
```

Comment: Still does'nt work like this:



<div id="search" class="search" style="margin-left: 20px;">
 <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Hvad leder du efter?.." name="search" value="<?php if(isset($search)) echo $search; ?>" />
 <button type="submit" class="button-search"></button>
    <input type="submit" style="display: none"/>
</div>

Comment: And you are using a <form action=...> tag? Maybe some browsers ignore hidden objects, so you could place them outside the screen. ... position: absolute; left: -500px;    ... are you able to submit the form by using the enter \ return key on desktop browsers?

Comment: Yes i am able to click enter on desktop thats what i dont understand

Answer (score 0):

hope this may help  by 
adding `form` tag with action  attribute targeting  the current url or search page

```
function get_current_url()
{
        $ssl = false;
        $hostname = 'example.org';
        return ($ssl ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $hostname . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


}

$q = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : false;
if($q !== false) {
     echo 'searching for :' . htmlspecialchars($q); 
}

?>

<div id="search" class="search" style="margin-left: 20px;">
<form method='GET' action='<?= $get_current_url; ?>' >
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="q" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['q'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']); ?>" />
<input type="submit" value='Search' class="button-search"></button>
</form>
</div>
```